# URLSession moving slow when caching a firebase video url

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I initially asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62873052/4833705), got the answer, and in the comments @LeoDabus said:

> NSData(contentsOf: url) it is not mean to use with non local resources
> urls

He suggested I use `URLSession` which I did, but the response is very slow. I'm wondering am I doing something wrong. The video is 2mb if that makes any difference.

Inside the the session's completionHandler I tried updating the returned data on the main queue but there was a scrolling glitch while doing that. Using `DispatchQueue.global().async` there is no scrolling glitch but it seems like it takes longer return

```
// all of this occurs inside my data model

var cachedURL: URL?

let videoUrl = dict["videoUrl"] as? String ?? "" // eg. "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myApp.appspot.com/o/abcd%277920FHqFBkl7D6j%2F-MC65EFG_qT0KZbdtFhU%2F48127-8C29-4666-96C9-E95BE178B268.mp4?alt=media&token=bf85dcd1-8cee-428e-87bc-91800b7316de"
guard let url = URL(string: videoUrl) else { return }

useURLSessionToCacheVideo(url)


func useURLSessionToCacheVideo(_ url: URL) {
    
    let lastPathComponent = url.lastPathComponent
    let cachesDir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let file = cachesDir.appendingPathComponent(lastPathComponent)
    
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: file.path) {

        self.cachedURL = file
        print("url already exists in cache")
        return
    }
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
        
        if let error = error { return }
        
        if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            guard response.statusCode == 200 else {
                return
            }
        }
        
        guard let data = data else {
            return
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.global().async { // main queue caused a hiccup while scrolling a cv
            do {
                try data.write(to: file, options: .atomic)
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    self?.cachedURL = file
                }
            } catch {
                print("couldn't cache video file")
            }
        }
        
    }).resume()
}
```

Comment: @Rob you lost me, you said love the write file to the main queue but do it on the background thread? Did you mean don’t do it on the background thread

Comment: No need to use dispatch queue global

Comment: @Rob Ok, thanks, I’ll switch to a download task and see what happens

Comment: Don’t forget to remove the dispach queue global

Comment: @LeoDabus I’m going to remove it and switch to using a download task like rob suggested. In your previous comments to my other question you also suggested that.as another alternative. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write the file from the session's background thread:

```
func useURLSessionToCacheVideo(_ url: URL) {
    let lastPathComponent = url.lastPathComponent

    let fileURL = try! FileManager.default
        .url(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        .appendingPathComponent(lastPathComponent)

    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
        self.cachedURL = fileURL
        print("url already exists in cache")
        return
    }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        guard
            error == nil,
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            200 ..< 300 ~= httpResponse.statusCode,
            let data = data
        else {
            return
        }

        do {
            try data.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                self?.cachedURL = fileURL
            }
        } catch {
            print("couldn't cache video file")
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

This also accepts any 2xx HTTP response code.

---

That having been said, I’d suggest using a download task, which reduces the peak memory usage and writes the data to the file as you go along:

```
func useURLSessionToCacheVideo(_ url: URL) {
    let lastPathComponent = url.lastPathComponent

    let fileURL = try! FileManager.default
        .url(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        .appendingPathComponent(lastPathComponent)

    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
        self.cachedURL = fileURL
        print("url already exists in cache")
        return
    }

    URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { location, response, error in
        guard
            error == nil,
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            200 ..< 300 ~= httpResponse.statusCode,
            let location = location
        else {
            return
        }

        do {
            try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: fileURL)
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                self?.cachedURL = fileURL
            }
        } catch {
            print("couldn't cache video file")
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

---

Personally, rather than having this routine update `cachedURL` itself, I'd use a completion handler pattern:

```
enum CacheError: Error {
    case failure(URL?, URLResponse?)
}

func useURLSessionToCacheVideo(_ url: URL, completion: @escaping (Result<URL, Error>) -> Void) {
    let lastPathComponent = url.lastPathComponent

    let fileURL = try! FileManager.default
        .url(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        .appendingPathComponent(lastPathComponent)

    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
        completion(.success(fileURL))
        return
    }

    URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { location, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
            return
        }

        guard
            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
            200 ..< 300 ~= httpResponse.statusCode,
            let temporaryLocation = location
        else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(.failure(CacheError.failure(location, response)))
            }
            return
        }

        do {
            try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: temporaryLocation, to: fileURL)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(.success(fileURL))
            }
        } catch {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

And call it like so:

```
useURLSessionToCacheVideo(url) { result in
    switch result {
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)

    case .success(let cachedURL):
        self.cachedURL = cachedURL
    }
}
```

That way, the caller is responsible for updating `cachedURL`, it now knows when it's done (in case you want to update the UI to reflect the success or failure of the download), and your network layer isn't entangled with the model structure of the caller.

Comment: Thanks, I was just writing the function to use download task. Your code is much better than what I was writing 

Comment: completionHandler is much better for this!